# Не могу скачать файл через написанный браузер (с гугл диска)

Tags: java, android

Написал браузер все работает но проблема в чем: я пытаюсь скачать с гугл диска     файл проходит загрузка и все (ничего не скачивает и ошибки не выдает !)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

//

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

//

```
  public class MainActivity2_3 extends AppCompatActivity {

        ProgressBar progressBar;

        WebView webView;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2_3);


            webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
            WebSettings webset = webView.getSettings();
            webset.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


            String loadUrl="https://drive.google.com/open?id=1j5uEZYQ2G4Xp1OnSRXpseNSpqz5wpGK1";



            webView.loadUrl(loadUrl);


            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                    progressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
                    if(newProgress==100)
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    else
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });


        }


    }
```

//

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

//

Comment: `webView.setDownloadListener(...)` и там могут быть варианты, сами качаете или открываете активити по uri и т.д.

Comment: как сделать  чтобы через мою загружало ?

Comment: Вооружайтесь okhttp, грузите файл в свой кэш или в downloads, только открывать скорее всего все равно придется в стороннем приложении.

Answer (score 0):

Я добавил этот код теперь загружается 
спасибо  Yura Ivanov . Но загрузку можно сделать только через другую программу как сделать , чтобы через мою загружало ?

```
 webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                        long contentLength) {

                Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Теперь грузит нормально но как сделать  нормальное имя при загрузке файла пишет (1hjdh3je)

```
   webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                        String contentDisposition, String mimeType,
                                        long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                        Uri.parse(url));


                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                                url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }});
```